# Android toolchain oddity

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (x64), Using android NDK I am trying to build the stand alone tool chain using the following command line:

```
/%Some path%/android-ndk-r7b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh' --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/%Some path%/Android/stand-aloone-toolchain
```

while trying to execute any of the resulting files, eg. './arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' I get 'bash: ./arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory'.
I have verified that the file has execute permissions, I have also verified it is a linux executable while checking that it starts with the 'ELF' notation...

Why my generated tool chain doesn't work, why do I get 'No such file or directory' while directly executing './arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' from it's local dir. ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu (x64), it appears that the OS doesn't include the libc & libz x32 version by default, installing libc6-i386 & lib32z1 resolved the problem..